# Display matrix in two dimension array

Tags: c

I am newbie in c and trying to display an array in matrix form. I have seen tutorials, but most of them deal with for loop to apply matrix concept in a 2-D array. i m using while loop and examining it in my way. It is although displaying in matrix form but it is not displaying the accurate output. If i insert numbers 1,2..,9, it must show in the form as below:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

but it is displaying as :

```
1 2 4
4 5 7
7 8 9
```

I am unable to understand why it is happening.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{

    int i=0,j=0;
    int arr[2][2];
    clrscr();
    while(i<=2)
    {
        j=0;
        while(j<=2)
        {
            scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    i=0;
    while(i<=2)
    {
        j=0;
        while(j<=2)
        {
            printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);

            //printf("%c",k);
            j++;
            //k++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d",arr[0][2]);
    getch();
```

Comment: Your array indexes are out of bounds. `int arr[2][2]` is only indexible to `arr[1][1]`. Remember, in C arrays are index from 0..(n-1) where n is the declared dimension. Change `int arr[2][2]` to `int arr[3][3]`. (and sidenote: fix `void main()`; the C-standard requires `main()` to return an `int`).

Comment: Surprised you are not getting a seg fault instead of wrong display. Your 2 x 2 array is being treated like a 3 x 3 array. That is what your problem is. Your array should be in the form `int arr[3][3];`

Comment: I don't know whether you just forgot or anything else... but there is no ending braces for function `main()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just need to declare two dimentional array in correct way store 9 elements  like this

```
int arr[3][3];  //3x3 =9 elements
```

you are declared arr[2][2] . this is two dimensional array which stores four elements 2x2 = 4

Comment: if array out of bounds is the problem, then why is the output exactly the same except the third arr[0][2] and arrr[1][2] places.

Comment: @Divyang if you try with different inputs you will get different ways output. simply i can say that is Undefined behavior

Comment: @Divyang because consider the most likely way to layout a 2D array in memory. If you access `arr[i][j]` and the second dimension is 2, the memory it hits will be `*(arr + 2*i + j)`. Then `arr[0][2]` and `arr[1][0]` will be the same position in memory since 2*0 + 2 == 1*2 + 0, and likewise `arr[1][2]` and `arr[2][0]` are aliased because 2*1 + 2 = 2*2 + 0. The whole third row is off the end of the array, but it happens to work anyway.

Comment: @Divyang naturally if you declare `int arr[3][3]`, not only do you get enough memory to avoid an overrun, but the multiplier in that formula becomes 3, which means you get a unique position in memory for every (valid) set of indices.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like, you are using a TurboC++ like IDE, but most of other IDE like `codeblocks` and linux `gcc` and `g++` compiler do not support `conio.h` header file and its functions like `clrscr()` and `getch()`, this is making your code less portable.

Your array size does not fulfills the requirement of your **3d matrix**, and the pattern you are getting is just a coincidence, in my linux platform it gives me this, when I tried to set array size `arr[2],[2]`.

`1` `2` `4` 
`4` `5` `1` 
`2` `1` `134513968`

Problems you are getting are here because of your lesser array size, not because of your while loop.

Try this,
This code initializes your array with size `arr[3][3]`, this will resolve your problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int i=0,j=0;
    int arr[3][3];
    while(i<=2)
    {
        j=0;
        while(j<=2)
        {
            scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    i=0;
    while(i<=2)
    {
        j=0;
        while(j<=2)
        {
            printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);

            //printf("%c",k);
            j++;
            //k++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d",arr[0][2]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: i tried coding c in netbeans..it executed c programs for a while, and then atart giving error: unable to create process: hostinfo unavailable

Comment: This kind of error is new to me, I'll recommend to reset your user preferences... or if you still see some problems you can reinstall your netbeans, Try using gcc or g++ compiler from command prompt

Comment: yes i did the same...installed netbeans, then installed cygwin packages and added gcc compiler and all that configurations accordingly..even executed some of the programs in it..suddenly it started showing hostinfo unavailable error... apart of doing whole process again, i preferred turbo c++

Comment: ohk..will give it a try

Comment: Yes, you should do that... Codeblocks is definitely better than TurboC++, TurboC++ is really obsolete ..Well, If you think I've suggested some good things through my answer you can vote it up.. ;)